# How to handle gridview button click with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, button, gridview, click

I have a GridView on my page. This GridView has a template defined as follows:

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EMAIL ADDRESS">
     <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtgvEmailAddress" Text = '<%# Eval("EMAIL")%>' runat="server" Width="300px" />
           <asp:Button ID="btnUpdateEmail" Text = "Update" runat="server" Width="70px" />
     </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

How can I handle a click of my txtgvEmailAddress button?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I have the following: $(document).ready(function () {
     
        $('#btnUpdateEmail').click(function() {
            alert("Clicked");
        });
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use OnClientClick event of button control.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdateEmail" Text = "Update" runat="server" Width="70px" OnClientClick="Show();" />

    function Show() {
    alert('Clicked');
    return false;
    }
```

Comment: I tried to do that but I got an error "Attribute 'ClientIDMode' is not valid"

Comment: @eugene.it, Please remove ClientIdMode from your button control.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

You can also delegate the click with [jQuery on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)